# Zend lucene : Multiple criteria on search = bad results

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I new to lucene, and i noticed something annoying :

In my search bar,

- if I type "USA" : return all the matches -> OK.
- If I type "Developper" : return all the matches -> OK

BUT,

-if i type "USA Developper", it'll not return me all the developper in the USA.

It'll return me some developper in UK, DE, FR + Developpers, Stars, Engineers in USA

How to fix that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set default search operator as AND. (Not sure how you do it in php.)

Or in your current framework, if you search for `+developer +usa` (ie prefix a `+` before each term) it will return you developers in USA.